# URLify a given String - replace spaces with %20

Tags: java, strings, comparative-review, complexity

I have written a code to replace all spaces in a `String` with `%20`.

```
Input: "Mr John Smith "
Output: "Mr%20John%20Smith"
```

My logic:

```
public class URLify {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Mr John Smith  ";
        str = str.stripTrailing();
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char c : ch) {
            if(c != ' ')
                sb.append(c);
            else {
                sb.append("%20");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The given solution:

```
static int MAX = 1000; 
static char[] replaceSpaces(char str[]) {
    int space_count = 0, i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            space_count++;
    while (str[i - 1] == ' ') {
        space_count--;
        i--;
    }
    int new_length = i + space_count * 2;
    if (new_length > MAX)
        return str;
    int index = new_length - 1;
    char[] old_str = str;
    str = new char[new_length];
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (old_str[j] == ' ') {
            str[index] = '0';
            str[index - 1] = '2';
            str[index - 2] = '%';
            index = index - 3;
        }
        else {
            str[index] = old_str[j];
            index--;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Both work correctly with a linear time complexity of () however, can someone please suggest which solution is a better one especially if asked in an interview? Thanks!

Comment: What was the language for the given solution?

Comment: The language was `java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does what you describe, but the code does *not* what it is really supposed to do.

You are not the first person ever who needs to convert an arbitrary string into a form that can be embedded in a URL. Several people before you have already solved this problem. The crucial point is to know how these people *named* the method or function or class or module where they implemented this function.

In Java, most network-related things are in the package `java.net`, and since URLs and URIs are network-related, they are there as well. Directly next to the classes `URL` and `URI` you will find the class `URLEncoder` that does all the work for you, including several edge cases you probably never heard of. Using this heavily tested and well-known piece of code is much better than rolling your own.

Hmmm, a pretty heavy down-side of Java's `URLEncoder` is that it is old and dusty and probably will not be updated anymore. It does not even encode spaces as `%20`, but as `+`, and the `+` is something that only works in the query string part of a URL.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/607176) describes the bad API that standard Java is providing for this use case. The encoding part of [this answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611117/225757) is good, the general Java approach is bad, as I wrote in the comment below that answer. So be careful and don't copy that code blindly.

Answer (score 2):

### Review

Welcome to Code Review. There are some suggestions as follows.

#### Consider to use `replaceAll`

The operation you performed is what [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) do, you can use `replaceAll` directly instead of `String.toCharArray()`, whitespace comparison, and `sb.append` things.

#### Create a method `URLify`

In order to improve usability, it is better to create a method `URLify` to perform this specific operation.

#### Summary

Combine all the things:

```
public class URLify {
    
    public static String URLify(String input){
        return input.stripTrailing().replaceAll(" ","%20");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Mr John Smith  ";
        System.out.println(URLify(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use `replaceAll`, a simple `replace` is sufficient. (Yes, I know that the method names are confusing, but they cannot be improved anymore since too much existing code relies on them.)